# Stata flag when word found, not strpos

Tags: string, stata

I have some data with strings, and I want to flag when a word is found. A word would be defined as at the start of the string, end, or separated a space. `strpos` will find whenever the string is present, but I am looking for something similar to `subinword`. Does Stata have a way to use the functionality of `subinword` without having to replace it, and instead flag the word?

```
clear 
input id str50 strings
1 "the thin th man"
2  "this old then"
3 "th to moon"
4 "moon blank th"
end

gen th_pos = 0
replace th = 1 if strpos(strings, "th") >0
```

This above code will flag every observation as they all contain "th", but my desired output is:

```
ID      strings          th_sub
1   "the thin th man"      1
2   "this old then"        0
3   "th to moon"           1
4   "moon blank th"        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small trick is that `"th"` as a word will be preceded and followed by a space, except if it occurs at the beginning or the end of string. The exceptions are no challenge really, as

```
gen wanted = strpos(" " + strings + " ", " th ") > 0
```

works around them. Otherwise, there is a rich set of regular expression functions to play with.

The example above flags that the code that doesn't do what you want condenses to one line,

```
gen th_pos = strpos(strings, "th") > 0
```

A more direct answer is that you don't have to replace anything. You just have to get Stata to tell you what would happen if you did:

```
gen WANTED = strings != subinword(strings, "th", "", .)
```

If removing a substring if present changes the string, it must have been present.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions can be useful for this type of exercise, with word boundaries allowing you to search for whole words indicated by `\b`, as in `"\bword\b"`.

```
gen wanted = ustrregexm(strings, "\bth\b")
```